# Browser-independent way to determine which CSS properties were overridden by style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

Is there any cross-browser way to determine which CSS properties were set manually via JavaScript? Or, possibly, which CSS attributes were overridden by style attribute?

Is `cssText` property standard and cross-browser: `document.getElementById('id').style.cssText`?

Another possible solution is to use wrapper function. Most simple example:

```
function css(node, prop, value)
{
   $(node).css(prop, value);
   memory[node][prop] = value;  // remember that we set prop for the node
}
```

Comment: Are there particular properties you're wanting to check? You could use this jQuery plugin: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx - you could set the old values onto the elements using data(). Just an idea... may not suit what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Shane Garelja: Funny plugin, but it monitors only predefined set of properties. I need to "monitor" all style properties that can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can always grab the style attribute and rip out the values:

Non JQuery idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="aspan" style="color:red; background-color: blue;">Hey Hey Hey</span>
    <script>

      String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
      }

      var sp = document.getElementById("aspan");
      var stys = sp.getAttribute("style").split(";");
      var rules = {};
      for(var i=0; i<stys.length;i++){        
        var sty = stys[i].split(":");
        if(sty.length>=2){
          rules[sty.shift().trim().toLowerCase()] = sty.join(":").trim();
        }
      }

      alert(rules["color"]);
      alert(rules["background-color"]);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/icaqa3/edit)

This will not catch what is added via JS code. aka `elem.style.foo="bar"`

Comment: This is half the answer to your question where you asked what is set with the style attribute. It does not cover the part with JavaScript setting it. Sorry I tried to give you some help. lol